# Firebase insecurity/public endpoints with iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've frequently heard that the main issue we need Firebase security rules is because an application contains all the configurations needed to connect to the database and thus users could do something like db.delete('*'), read/write whatever they want, etc. etc.

I can see how this is possible on a web app, as you could check out the requests being sent over the network and thus get the endpoint needed to connect to the database, but, on an iOS app, how would this be possible?

For instance, say I created some chat app with Firebase and released it to the App Store. When a user downloads it, how would he/she gain access to my database through an API other than the buttons etc I provide with them with? Is there something equivalent to the "Network" section in google chrome that shows all outgoing requests, and, from, this they could send a malicious request to my database? Would this require installing 3rd party software onto their device to see all outgoing/incoming requests and they could get the required endpoint/database connection info from there?

Thanks.

Comment: There are multiple ways to inspect network traffic on mobile device.   Google Charles proxy and iOS man in the middle attack as two easy example searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a user downloads it, how would he/she gain access to my database through an API other than the buttons etc I provide with them with?

It's not hard to reverse engineer the contents of the IPA file to get both the configuration you provided, and also see what the code is that queries the database.  The IPA file can be obtained pretty easily - there is not much protecting that, given the user effectively has full control over the device (e.g. jailbreak).  Given that information, it's possible to simply invoke the public [Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api) to not just duplicate all the operations in the app, and but invent operations of their own.

Comment: ah alright so the key is the IPA file. Yeah I guess that just always confused me because if I go on the app store and download an app I'm just downloading the app, but I've never seen the IPA file, but I guess that makes sense - you need extra modifications/software like a jail break to directly read the IPA file, so it'd be a somewhat involved process but still nonetheless possible, thank you!

Comment: You don't actually need to jailbreak the device to see an IPA.  You could get the IPA from a site that illegally hosts the file.  Coordinated efforts to find secrets, break security in computer software have been around for decades.